# What exactly is being asked in Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11, "Significance of the Derivative", problem 49, regarding Cauchy Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following is a problem from chapter 10, "Significance of the Derivative", from Spivak's Calculus:

> 49. Prove that the conclusion of the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem can be written in the form
>
> $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\tag{1}$$
>
> under the additional assumptions that $g(b) \neq g(a)$ and that
> $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are never simultaneously $0$ on $(a,b)$.

I am not sure exactly what is being asked here.

Here is the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem as it appears in Spivak's Calculus

> Theorem 8 (The Cauchy Mean Value Theorem) If $f$ and $g$ are
> continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there is a
> number $x$ in $(a,b)$ such that
>
> $$[f(b)-f(a)]g'(x)=[g(b)-g(a)]f'(x)$$
>
> (If $g(b) \neq g(a)$, and $g'(x) \neq 0$, this equation can be written
>
> $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Starting from the consequent of the theorem, we need only the additional assumptions $g(b) \neq g(a)$ and $g'(x) \neq 0$ to reach $(1)$. Problem 49 is asking us to alter the second assumption to say that $g'(x)$ and $f'(x)$ can't both be 0 simultaneously. This would seem to imply that $g'(x)$ can in fact be zero.

Here is the solution from the solution manual

> We have
>
> $$[f(b)-f(a)]g'(x)=[g(b)-g(a)]f'(x)$$
>
> If $g'(x)=0$, then $f'(x)[g(b)-g(a)]=0$. But this contradicts the
> assumption that $g(b) \neq g(a)$, and the fact that $f'(x) \neq 0$
> (since $g'(x) = 0$).

If we assume $g'(x) =0$ then we can't have $f'(x) \neq 0$ and $g(b) \neq g(a)$ simultaneously, that much is clear. But how does this imply that we can write $(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy Mean-Value theorem says there exists some x where the equality is satisfied. You aren't assuming that for that specific x, g'(x) would be 0, however that wherever g' is 0, f' isn't (and vice-versa). Hence, for the specific x found by the Cauchy Mean-Value theorem, g'(x) is also non-zero, hence the second form.